# If I multiply delta by 10, will I get negative effects on slower machines? [LIBGDX]

Tags: java, animation, libgdx, timedelta

While working on a minimalistic animation for a project, I've found that multiplying by delta yields results that are too slow (animation wise). To combat this, I tried multiplying delta by 10. This gave me the faster animation I was looking for.

Would this cause choppiness on machines with a fluctuating fps?

Any help would be appreciated.

Slower animation:

```
leftX += ((leftTargetX - leftX) / 2) * delta;
```

Faster animation, multiplying delta by 10:

```
leftX += ((leftTargetX - leftX) / 2) * (delta * 10);
```

Any and all help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: no sprockets is working ok

Comment: You are not "really" multiplying the delta. You are multiplying the value multiplied by the delta. Rewrite it as `10 * ((leftTargetX - leftX) / 2) * delta` to see. Multiplying it by 10 thus scales the computed value to be applied for the given delta. It is the purpose of the delta to minimize fluctuations in output based on machine performance.

Comment: Ah you're right. Thank you, appreciate it. @user2864740

Comment: Anyway, a delta is a good first step. A slightly improved mode (when there can be accuracy errors in calculations which matters for 'perfect synchronization') is to pick a fixed calculations per second and to do the math, eg, every 1/60th of a second. Then, instead of using a dynamic delta, perform 1..n math frames (each only does 1/60th second work) on each render - as needed to "be in sync" with the current time.

Comment: I'll look into that. Thank you for the informative lead @user2864740